# What is the difference between these two way to define a list in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Is there any difference between these two way to define `list` in Python?

```
lst1=[1,2]
lst2=[1,2,]
```

If there is no difference between then, Why Python define these two way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly for convenience, especially when defining multi-line lists.

```
mylist = [
    1,
    2,
    3,
]
```

The trailing comma makes it a little easier to add new items or reorder them. If you get in the habit of always leaving a trailing comma, then bugs due to forgetting to remove a comma go away.

Comment: It also means that if you add a new item to the list, the diff will only be 1 line, not 2.  This sounds like a very minor thing, but when working in large groups it becomes important because it makes "git diff" look a lot cleaner, makes reverts and merges more likely to happen without fail.